# How to make detail section undivided in JasperReport

Tags: java, layout, jasper-reports

How can i be ensured that every detail section won't be separated in diffenent pages?
If two detail sections aren't able to fit into one page without second devision into two parts, then they must be set into two pages. I don't want the second detail section been divided.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using iReport?  If so, simply click the detail node in the outline window (that tree structure on the left of the screen) to bring up the properties for that band. The properties window will appear on the right side of the screen.  Where it says Split Type, select "Prevent" from the drop down menu.  If you are coding your report in jrxml, when you get to the `<detail>` tag, in its first child tag, `<band>` set the attribute `splitType="Prevent"`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it tomorrow at work. I knew that it must be supported :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is a better way of doing it but you can do it by checking the sum of the sizes divisions being greater than or less than the total size total size of page. If it is less than the size of the page you don't need to do anything but if it is greater you can simply take out the last division and put it on the other page. There would be some way of pagination in JasperReport, try googling it. Hope it works for you.